# Error when inject service into startup constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new in C#. I'm trying to migrate a project from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1. I have the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Dionis._1.TracingOptions' while attempting to activate
>   'Dionis._1.Startup'.'

at this line `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` in program.cs.

Startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, TracingOptions tracingOptions)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _tracingOptions = tracingOptions;
        }
```

It was working in ASP.NET Core 2.2. What's wrong? I need to get `TracingOptions` because I use it for `services.AddTracing(_tracingOptions);` in `ConfigureService`s method

Comment: Did you made any code changes to port application to asp.net core 3.1? I don't see Startup class. Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and next https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)?

[It says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder)

> The most significant change from `WebHostBuilder` to `HostBuilder` is
>   in dependency injection (DI). When using `HostBuilder`, you can only
>   inject the following into `Startup`'s constructor:
>
> - IConfiguration
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IWebHostEnvironment

You cannot do it in this way anymore. Instead, in Startup.cs try something like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other services

    TracingOptions tracingOptions = Configuration.GetSection("YOUR_SECTION_NAME").Get<TracingOptions>());
    services.AddTracing(tracingOptions);
}
```

Comment: Yes, sir. I use it document. seems I missed it :/

Comment: Should I move this code from Program.cs to Startup.cs now?

Comment: I have this code in program.cs `TracingOptions tracing = new TracingOptions(); context.Configuration.GetSection("Tracing").Bind(tracing); services.AddSingleton<TracingOptions>(ctx => tracing);` what does `Get<TracingOptions>()` do?

Comment: It will do the same but without creating an instance of `TracingOptions`. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#getvalue)

Comment: Glad to have been of help